# Creating a PersistentVolume with non-existent storage class succeeds

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating the following PersistentVolume

```yaml
▶ cat mypv.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: myvolume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: normal
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/etc/foo"
```

However, after creating

```
▶ k create -f mypv.yaml
persistentvolume/myvolume created
```

I realized that there is no `normal` `StorageClass` available.

```
▶ k get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false                  8d
```

So how come a `PersistentVolume` creation with a non-existent storage class succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `hostPath` case `storageClassName` actually is not ignored.
It is still used for PVC binding.

> The configuration file specifies that the volume is at /mnt/data on
> the cluster's Node. <...>
> It defines the StorageClass name manual
> for the PersistentVolume, which will be used to bind
> PersistentVolumeClaim requests to this PersistentVolume.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume

And also it may be used for Dynamic Provisioning, in case the cluster provides dynamic provisioner for `hostPath` (as Minikube does).

Answer (score 2):

Note that storage class is called when volume needs to be provisioned dynamically. It works well on cloud providers like GCD, AWS , Azure.

On the other hand, HostPath volumes are provisioned statically. Storage class is ignored in those PV definitions. Hence in your case the pv was created without errors. The pv is bound to the storage on the host machine.

Follow the below link for help --> https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-hostpath.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) enabled, you can create a storage class on-demand. MiniKube has its [own](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/) dynamic provisioning which uses *hostpath*